# unbind $scope param from var angular

Tags: angularjs

I have $scope.attributesList = [{name:"",val:""}....]

in some cases I need to copy my list and unbind it from my destination param.

var param = $scope.attributesList;

the problem is each time $scope.attributesList changed my param also changed, I need my param to be static after I copied my $scope.attributesList and not to changed. What is the way to unbind it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a deep copy of the object, to do that use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
var param = angular.copy($scope.attributesList);
```

if we using like `var param = $scope.attributesList;` then both `param` and `$scope.attributesList` are pointed to same object because `$scope.attributesList` is a reference type

If we use primitive type like `1,2` as,

```
 $scope.attributesList = 1;
 var param = $scope.attributesList;
```

then `param` and `$scope.attributesList` are independent.